# Collection inside the other collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have a CSV holding a function data in it.

It has function ID,Name,Description.

and also it has say 50 records.

for all the records the  function ID,Name,Description will remain same.
so i want to create a collection say Func( for common details ) and want to create another collection inside that Func collection ( for the records)

That is for all the records function ID,Name,Description will be same.

Can i create a collection inside the other collection?

Comment: I don't understand the structure of this CSV - could you post a few rows from it?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following document satify your needs?

The ID, Name and Description information is stored at the top level of the document. Then the `func_info` field can contain an array of sub-documents containing the records for that function.

```
{
 "ID" : "id1",
 "Name" : "function1",
 "Description" : "function to add numbers",
 "func_info" :[ 
    {
        "input1" : 20,
        "input2" : 30,
        "output" : 50
    },
    {
        "input1" : 7,
        "input2" : 7,
        "output" : 14
    }    
 ]
}
```